# How and where to add this css to a vf page?

Tags: visualforce

The following CSS is supposed to make a very bland table look nice. I got if from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_fancy).

Where to put it and call it so it works for my vf page.

```
<style>
    #customers {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }    
    #customers td,#customers th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    #customers tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2
    }
    #customers tr:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    #customers th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the controller

```
public class vfCtrlr_Show_Training_Schedule {

    //This next line allows this controller to pass data to the VF page vf_BOG_Committee_Report.vfp
    public String htmlCode { get; private set;} 
    public Id oppid{get;set;}
    public boolean ShowLogin {get; set;}
    public boolean ShowTrainingSchedule {get; set;}
    public String usrEmail {get; set;}


public vfCtrlr_Show_Training_Schedule() 
    { 
    //  ID usrID = UserInfo.getUserId();
//        Id userId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');

    //  First show login screen and hide student schedule section
        showLogin = true;
        showTrainingSchedule = false;      

    }

    public void lookupUser()
    {
        List<Contact> c = [select ID,Email from Contact where Email = : usrEmail limit 1];        
        if (c.size() > 0) 
        {
            showSchedule();
            showLogin = false;
            showTrainingSchedule = true;               
        }else
        {
            htmlCode = 'We are sorry but we can not find that email in our system. ';
            showLogin = false;
            showTrainingSchedule = true;               

        }

    }
    public void cancelAction()
        { 
        }  
    public void showSchedule()
    {
            // Get all records from object     
        List<Training__c> queryList = [Select Teacher__r.FirstName, Name, Start_Date__c,Start_Time__c,End_Time__c,Trainer__c
                            FROM Training__c 
                            WHERE Teacher__r.Primary_email__c = :usrEmail AND Teacher__r.name like '%community%' AND Teacher__r.Active_Candidate__c = True
                            ORDER BY Start_Date__c,Start_Time__c]; 
    DateTime prevStartDate = DateTime.now();
    DateTime currStartDate = DateTime.now();

        Integer cntNumMemberships=0;
        htmlCode =''; // The variable we return to the VF page
        String currRecord = '';

//       htmlCode = htmlCode+ '<h3>Hi ' + queryList[0].Teacher__r.FirstName   + '!</h3> <br /><br />Welcome to Jasmin. Below is your training schedule. If you have any questions feel free to email info@jafi.org. <table border=1>'; //wrap info in HTML table in a table to dispaly properly
//  htmlCode = '<head><style>table, th, td {    border: 1px solid black;}</style></head>';     
    htmlCode = htmlCode+ '<h3>Hi ' + queryList[0].Teacher__r.FirstName   + '!</h3> <br /><br />Welcome. <table id="tbl1"> '; //wrap info in HTML table in a table to display properly

          for(Training__c record :queryList)
          { 
              currStartDate = record.Start_Date__c;
              if (currStartDate.Date() == prevStartDate.date())
                {
                    htmlCode = htmlCode + '<tr><td>'+ record.Name +'</td>'+ '<td>'+ record.Start_Time__c.format('hh:mm a') +'</td>'+ '<td>'+ record.End_Time__c.format('hh:mm a') +'</td></tr>';          
                }
              else
              {
                  htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table><br /><br /><br /><table id="tbl2"><tr><th>For the Date of: '+currStartDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd') +'</th></tr><tr><tr><th>Class</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th></tr><tr><td>'+ record.Name +'</td>'+ '<td>'+ record.Start_Time__c.format('hh:mm a') +'</td>'+ '<td>'+ record.End_Time__c.format('hh:mm a') +'</td></tr>';          
              }  
            prevStartDate = record.Start_Date__c;

        } 
        htmlCode = htmlCode + '</table>'; 

    }
}
```

Here is the VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="vfCtrlr_Show_Training_Schedule" showHeader="false">

    <center>

    <br />

    <h3>
       <br /><br /> Training Schedule for 2016<br /> 
    </h3>
    </center>

        <apex:form rendered="{!showLogin}"> 
        <apex:pageblock>           
            Please enter your email address: &nbsp;<apex:inputText  id="email" value="{!usrEmail}" />  

                            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                                <apex:commandButton onclick="return validateFunction('{!$Component.email}');" action="{!lookupUser}" value="Submit"/>
                                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancelAction}" value="Cancel" reRender="none"/>
                            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageblock>    
        </apex:form>


  <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!showTrainingSchedule}">   
        <center>
        <br />
        <strong>Generated&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}"> 
        <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" /> 
        </apex:outputText>
            <br /><br /><br />

        </center>

        <div>    
        <apex:outputText value="{!htmlCode }" escape="false" />
        <br /><br /><br />
        </div>

    </apex:pageBlock>       
         <!-- Java script starts Here -->
  <script>
   function validateFunction(email){

       // Check for the email

       var input1 = document.getElementById(email).value;

       // Validate that the user typed in an email
       if(input1 == '' || input1 == null) {alert('Please enter your email:');return false}

  }
  </script> 
 <!-- java script ends here -->  

</apex:page>
```

Comment: How are you generating your table? Is it <apex:pageBlockTable?

Comment: Before I posted this question, I tried what Fernando and Mukesh suggested. it didn't work.  You're question to me is probably where the answer lies. I am new to developing so when I need to show data in a VF page, I just generate the whole page in HTML in the controller and send it to the VF page in one long string and let the browser render it. So when I paste CSS in, it didn't work. I didn't think it mattered so i didn't mention it in the question. Any ideas how to get the CSS to work? I didn't work when I put it in the long html string.

Comment: Can you post some of code from VF page and Controller.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Example using apex:dataTable and apex:repeat. The second approach gives you more flexibility in the styling IMO. Easiest ways to go. I commented out optional footers and captions for the dataTable.

Example Controller:

```
public class TableStylingCtrl {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get {
            if(setCon == null) {
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    [SELECT Name, Type FROM Account LIMIT 20]));
            }
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }
    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return (List<Account>) setCon.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Example Page: **Note:** I changed #customers from a div to class .customers

```
<apex:page controller="TableStylingCtrl">
    <style>
        .customers {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }    
        .customers td, .customers th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        .customers tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2
        }
        .customers tbody tr:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        .customers th {
            padding-left: 8px;
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }    
        .customers caption {
            color: #999;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .container-customers {
            margin: 15px 0;
        }
        /* Set footer background color */
        .customers tfoot {
            background-color: #999;
        }
        /* Set footer text color and alignment */
        .customers tfoot td {
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <!--Apex dataTable Example-->
    <apex:dataTable value="{!accounts}" var="account" styleClass="customers">   
        <!--Optional caption
        <apex:facet name="caption">Account Table</apex:facet>
        -->
                <!--Optional footer
        <apex:facet name="footer">Table Footer</apex:facet>
        -->
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
            <!--Optional footer
            <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
            -->
            <apex:outputText value="{!account.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">Type</apex:facet>
            <!--Optional footer
            <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
            -->
            <apex:outputText value="{!account.Type}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>
    <!--Apex repeat example--> 
    <div class="container-customers">
       <table class="customers">
            <caption>Account Table</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <!--Optional footer spanned across bottom-->
                    <td colspan="100%">
                        Optional Footer
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="account">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!account.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!account.Type}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>   
            </tbody>
        </table>       
    </div>      
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put it any place in you page. Or load it as an static resource.

Take a look at [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom.htm) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Visualforce implementation:

```
<apex:page >
   <style>
      #customers {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      }
      #customers td, #customers th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
      }
      #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
      #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
      #customers th {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      }
   </style>
   <Table id="customers" >
      <TR>
         <TH>Customer Name</TH>
         <TH>Address</TH>
      </TR>
      <TR>
         <TD>Some Customer Name</TD>
         <TD>Some Customer Address</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
         <TD>Some Customer Name</TD>
         <TD>Some Customer Address</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
         <TD>Some Customer Name</TD>
         <TD>Some Customer Address</TD>
      </TR>
   </Table>
</apex:page>
```

This example uses id css selector #customers. Similarly you can apply style to `<apex:datatable>` component or other vf table components.